# Nested scp for remote folder copying

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, nested, scp

**Objective:** I am trying to copy a folder and its files from HOST_C to HOST_A. `ssh` or `scp` can only be done through HOSTB due to keys.

**Infrastructure:**

```
HOST_A<-->HOST_B<-->HOST_C
```

**Current procedure:**

```
ssh to host_B
scp -r from folder at C to folder on B
exit ssh from B
scp -r from  folder on B to folder on A
ssh to host_B again
rm -r folders created
```

I have made some attempts using ProxyCommand but without luck.

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could connect from host B to host C with ssh, create a tar archive of the folder to copy and send the output to STDOUT and pipe all this to a second ssh session which connects to host A and unpacks the tar archive received on STDIN.

`ssh host_C "cd /somewhere; tar czpf - folder" | ssh host_A "cd /somewhere; tar xzpf -"`